# OSM (Open Street Map) help for a newbie

Tags: gis, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a couple of issues:

I am trying to add my own marker to a map, but it does not seem to work.
Also when I try to refer the OpenLayer.js file locally the default red marker disappears.

I have found some examples on the net, but they have been unsuccessful I am afraid. So  I thought to ask for some help here.

Now my code looks like this:

```
    <div id="Map" style="height: 250px; width: 400px" ></div>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<%--<script src="js/osm/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>--%>
<script>
    var lat = 55.676098;
    var lon = 12.568337;
    var zoom = 11;

    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

    map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(mapnik);

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");//("Images/Icons/map-marker.png");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

    map.setCenter(position, zoom);
</script>
```

and as you can see I have tried to refer to my own marker from 'Images/Icons/map-marker.png' without any luck.

Also you can see that I have tried to use a local copy of the 'OpenLayers.js', I don't know whether I should have it locally or always refer to 'www.openlayers.org', I believe referring local is good enough?

Also as I wrote earlier, if I refer the local .js file, the red marker, the zoom buttons and the OSM link disappears.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You are actually asking a question about *OpenLayers*, not *OpenStreetMap*)

The [OpenLayers Marker](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html) documentation provides an example for a custom marker icon. You have to create a *OpenLayers.Icon* object:

```
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(32,32);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("Images/Icons/map-marker.png", size, offset);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position, icon));
```

Where did you get your local *OpenLayers.js* copy from? It might be outdated if it doesn't work compared to the one version. And that's usually the reason why you want to keep a local copy of your libraries, because they won't change to a newer version automatically.

You should also make sure that the example you got from the web is up to date. Ideally you use one of the [official OpenLayers examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/).

Instead of OpenLayers you can also give the more modern and easier to use [LeafLet library](http://leafletjs.com/) a try.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to Leaflet. I have just done some initial samples with Leaflet library and it seems quiet easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found this at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marker_API:

```
marker = new khtml.maplib.overlay.Marker({
    position: new khtml.maplib.LatLng(0, 0),
    icon: {
            url: "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_de/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-pushpin.png",
            size: {width: 26, height: 32},
            origin: {x: 0, y: 0},
            anchor: {
                    x: "-10px",
                    y: "-32px"
            }
    },
    shadow: {
            url: "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_de/mapfiles/ms/micons/pushpin_shadow.png",
            size: {
                    width: "40px",
                    height: "32px"
            },
            origin: {x: 0, y: 0},
            anchor: {x: 0, y: -32 }
    },
    draggable: true,
    title: "moveable marker"
```

});

Comment: Thanks. I found that out too. However it is not a requirement for me to use openlayers. If someone can provide with a very simple script that can use a custom icon as marker for marking on map I would be deeply grateful.